# Specify gulp-inject Script Type

Tags: gulp, reactjs, gulp-inject

I am using JSX with React. Is it possible to specify the type of the injected script in order to use the in-browser JSX transformer while working in dev mode?

```
<!-- inject:js -->
<script type="text/jsx" src="js/components/Component.js"></script>
<!-- endinject -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gulp-inject considers JSX a different type than JavaScript. If you change the file suffix to `.jsx` and use the start tag `inject:jsx` instead of `inject:js`, the output contains the `type="text/jsx"` attribute.

Another option (if you need to keep the `.js` suffix) is to override the default transform function:

```
var inject = require('gulp-inject');

inject.transform.html.js = function (path) {
  return '<script type="text/jsx" src="'+path+'"></script>';
};
```